# How do I convert MySQLValue to correct type in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am using the [mysql-haskell](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mysql-haskell) package. The result of a query is of type IO [[MySQLValue]].

Now accessing the third value of a row like in the code below will print out **"MySQLInt16U 5"**:

```
test2 (x:xs) = show $ x!!2
```

How can I "convert" those MySQLValues to Integers, Strings or other native types (In this case the type should be Int)?

EDIT: [link reference for decoding types](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mysql-haskell-0.8.3.0/docs/Database-MySQL-Protocol-MySQLValue.html)

Comment: `MySQLValue` is just a big sum type, so pattern match on the constructor you expect to get, and throw an appropriate error for the other cases (e.g. `\case { MySQLInt16U x -> x; _ -> error "bad value" }`)